# What is the correct way to handle changes.watch webhook requests?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, webhooks

I'm trying to watch for google drive changes, and write down history of changes in database, also I want to store the files (all versions).
For now I have set up webhook, so I get some info in request.header, but this info looks weird, only message number differs, resourceUri or pageToken in it are the same.
Request headers don't contain info about file or folder that was changed. No change id, no file id, no actors.
I want to know, how this method is helpful and what should I do to get real-time changes with information about files that were changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps to handle Drive file changes.

### 1. Choose the change type you want to track

It could be just changes within the file, changes in the file metadata, such as moving the file to another folder or to a shared drive. You might want to use the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive) for that one.

### 2. Watch for changes

You can use the [Changes API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes) to detect what data has changed or has been removed. If you want detailed information about the changes, you can also check the [Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest)

### 3. Get the notification

Set up a webhook when changes are detected on the file

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://example.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myFilesChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
}
```

Sample code from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push

### 4. Export the new version of the file

After a new change is triggered, you can download the new file version using the [`export`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) method

You can check a more detailed guide on https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using Changes API, and in requests from changes.watch() I have only id, expiration, state, message-number, resource-id and resource-uri, no info about file that was changed or change id. How can I retrieve this? I mean, If I try to list changes at the same time when the webhook method was called, the last change in list could be not the same change that triggered webhook.. I am curious about that.
Also, your example in third part is about one file, but I need to watch changes from all files (could be more than 500 files) :(

Comment: Let me create an app and reproduce it to see how it can be done. Just some questions, what type of changes do you need to track? content changes? or do you just want to see who made a change in the file? What type of notification do you expect to track? do you have Google Workspace and are you an admin?

Comment: I came up with this: first, I get change webhook request, then I fetch latest changes (storing token in db), and finally I use drive activity to get details. Thank you!